# A platform for easy creation of custom websites?

Tags: web-services

I'm in a small business of hosting my clients' websites, and a lot of times they ask me to create one from scratch. I'm no designer, but I can code CSS/HTML, AJAX, PHP. However, I'm *not* willing to create sites from scratch, knowing how much is involved.

In the past, I've tried using design templates, but they proved to be inefficient - customers would request changes and I'd be unable to assist them, since I didn't write the template. Customers themselves would not be able to make changes.

So, the question is: **Is there web-based software that allows for easy creation of custom websites, with skins/layouts/templates? It should allow non-technical person to add content and make basic modifications.** I've seen a few websites use [Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress) for that purpose, but don't know if it's a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Joomla is huge and heavy, is not a reliable solution. I recommend you [Movable Type](http://www.movabletype.org/). It's written in PERL but have native support for multi-sites and multi-domains. Which is kinda cool :) Also, You can try [Expression Engine](http://expressionengine.com/) whch also have some nice features for multi-domain users with one setup.
Anyhow, the best solution is to build a custom solution for this, but of course, you won't be only a hosting company anymore :D

Answer (score 5):

If it has to be dead easy, then look at something like Joomla. If you want a bit more control, try Drupal. I think that both will suit you better than WordPress if my hunch is right.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are basically looking for a CMS. Now the problem is that there a so many CMS'es out there that it can be overwhelming to pick one. Another thing I've noticed over the years is that with the vast amount of CMS systems to pick from there is a lot of personal taste involved. To pick the one that suits you best you need to try out a bunch of them. I suggest you head over to [CMSMatrix](http://www.cmsmatrix.org/) and browse through the assortment and familiarize yourself with some of them.

(PS: Don't forget to try out [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org))

Answer (score 1):

I've used Wordpress for a very simple site which proved a right decision for it. You can check out that site at: [Chhobi.net](http://www.chhobi.net). If you don't have many complex requirements, I think Wordpress is not a bad idea. If you need to expand the site later on, and add different functionality (like forums, gallery, polls, etc.) you better go for a proper CMS solution like Joomla, Drupal, and likewise.